# Truffle - new MyContract() returns an address 0x000

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to test my code in Truffle but I'm facing something weird, when I create a new contract instance in one my functions, it seems to have the address 0x0000.

My function:

```
function createNewPot(string memory _name, string memory _description) public {
        uint newPotIndex = lastPotIndex++;
        potList[newPotIndex] = new Pot(this, newPotIndex, _name, _description, msg.sender);
}
```

My test:

```
describe('Pot creation', () => {
        it('creates a new pot', async () => {
            const title = "Titre de dingue"
            const description = "Description de ouf"

            await potManager.createNewPot(title, description, { from: sophie })
            let lastPotIndex = await potManager.lastPotIndex.call()
            let potCreatedAddress = await potManager.potList.call(lastPotIndex)

            console.log({ potCreatedAddress })
        })
    })
```

And here is the result of my console.log:
`{ potCreatedAddress: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' }`

Do you know why am I not receiving a valid address ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here :

```
uint newPotIndex = lastPotIndex++;
```

This is a post incrementation so basically equivalent to :

```
uint newPotIndex = lastPotIndex;
lastPotIndex = lastPotIndex + 1;
```

By opposition to a pre incrementation equivalent to :

```
lastPostIndex = lastPostIndex + 1;
uint newPotIndex = lastPotIndex;
```

So when you call :

```
let lastPotIndex = await potManager.lastPotIndex.call()
```

You get the index of the `newPotIndex + 1` ( because you did a post incrementation and you are getting `potList[lastPotIndex]` or `potList[newPotIndex + 1]`) which is not initialized, so defaults to a value of 0. Your code should revert on arrays, so I assume that `potList` is a mapping.

I suppose that the value you meant to display is accessible through :

```
let potCreatedAddress = await potManager.potList.call(lastPotIndex - 1)
```

Be careful to the special case where `lastPotIndex` == 0 though.

Comment: Dude, you rock !